# FlexibleSearchService doesn't work with fork join pool (hybris)

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a rest api controller that take a huge collection of elements, search each element in DB ,update fields then save updated objectin DB
Response is really slow so i want to use some kind of async calls.
My code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "qwerty/", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {"application/xml"},
            produces = "application/xml")
    @ResponseBody
    public PriceResponceDTOCollection performTask(@RequestBody PriceDataDTOCollection priceList){
final List<PriceError> priceErrorList = new ArrayList<>();
final List<PriceError> priceErrorList = new ArrayList<>();
            final List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList();
            for (final PriceData price : priceList.getPriceList()) {
                futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->priceService.setPrice(price)).thenAccept(priceErrorList::add));
            }
            futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).count();

}
```

This is priceservice's `setPrice`method

```
@Autowired
private FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService;
public PriceError setPrice(Price data){
   //building query
   //initialize map with params
   return flexibleSearchService.search(query.toString(),params).getResult().get(0);
}
```

Then i get NPE in `de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.impl.DefaultSessionService.executeInLocalView(DefaultSessionService.java:94)`

BTW , if my controller look's like this(without Fork join pool):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "qwerty/", method = RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = {"application/xml"},
                produces = "application/xml")
        @ResponseBody
        public PriceResponceDTOCollection performTask(@RequestBody PriceDataDTOCollection priceList){
    final List<PriceError> priceErrorList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final PriceData price : priceList.getPriceList()) {
                PriceError err = priceService.setPrice(price);
                priceErrorList.add(err);
            }

    }
```

everything work perfect. What is the reason (I also tried `priceList.getPriceList().parallelstream()` and also get NPE)

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim I dud work around , in my service I inject JdbcTemplate (spring class) and using JdbcTemplate I do batch insert/update . I didn't find how to do it using Flexible Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion updating price via web service is critical operation. Maybe you can convert updates as impex and call impex import service. Impex engine has parallel processing and other protections.